# Does the protocol used by HTTP proxies reduce the number of connections negotiated by the client?

Tags: performance, http, tcp, http-proxy

When an HTTP proxy server is used, is the number of connections negotiated between the client and the proxy reduced as compared to the client connecting directly to various http sites directly (without proxy)?

For example, when connecting directly to two different domains, it is clear that at least two connections must be made. In the case of a proxy, does the client usually use a single connect to the proxy for both "connections"?

Similarly, are there cases where a client that connecting to a single domain but accessing several resources would see a reduced number of connections using a proxy? E.g., can the proxy present a HTTP/1.1-style persistent connect even when the ultimate destination doesn't support it? Are proxies able to use longer persistent connection timeout periods?

Answer (score 1):

> In the case of a proxy, does the client usually use a single connect to the proxy for both "connections"?

While it would possible to use the same connection to a HTTP proxy to include HTTP requests to different targets most clients don't do it from what I've seen. Also, it would only work with HTTP and not HTTPS since in the latter case the whole TLS connection to the target is tunneled through the proxy and the close of this tunneled connection is also the close of the underlying TCP connection to the proxy. And, HTTP requests to multiple targets would only be possible with a HTTP proxy but not a SOCKS proxy since SOCKS essentially builds a tunnel to a specific target and this target is set at the beginning of the connection and can never be changed.

That said, while I've not seen it for browser to proxy connections I've seen a patched squid used (long ago) to do this in order to optimize proxy to proxy connections.

> E.g., can the proxy present a HTTP/1.1-style persistent connect even when the ultimate destination doesn't support it?

While this would be possible too it is also not common. Usually the proxy does not fully decouple client and server, i.e. a server-triggered close of the connection between server and proxy usually results in close of the connection between proxy and client too. The reason is probably that it would work for only for HTTP anyway and not HTTPS and that it makes the implementation of the proxy more complex since things like repeating a request on sudden close of a persistent connection by the server between requests would now need to be handled by the proxy instead of simply forwarding the close and let the client deal with it.